# Как разделить данные (API) Вывести в нужном виде

Tags: api

Есть код АПИ

На выходе получаю вот такие данные:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"AER":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AER","price":4170,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":579,"departure_at":"2019-11-30T22:45:00Z","return_at":"2019-12-19T03:00:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T10:57:32Z"},"AYT":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"AYT","price":6944,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":839,"departure_at":"2019-12-10T07:20:00Z","return_at":"2019-12-13T11:40:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-27T20:54:43Z"},"BCN":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"BCN","price":6988,"transfers":0,"airline":"FV","flight_number":5731,"departure_at":"2019-07-28T12:40:00Z","return_at":"2019-08-07T07:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T12:40:00Z"},"DPS":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"DPS","price":25874,"transfers":1,"airline":"SQ","flight_number":361,"departure_at":"2019-11-25T12:10:00Z","return_at":"2019-12-26T12:15:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T11:54:12Z"},"EVN":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"EVN","price":7242,"transfers":1,"airline":"DP","flight_number":855,"departure_at":"2019-10-12T13:50:00Z","return_at":"2019-10-18T12:50:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T06:21:25Z"},"IST":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"IST","price":6880,"transfers":0,"airline":"PC","flight_number":387,"departure_at":"2020-01-21T12:25:00Z","return_at":"2020-01-28T08:50:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-26T07:46:29Z"},"KGD":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"KGD","price":4400,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":261,"departure_at":"2019-11-07T05:25:00Z","return_at":"2019-11-12T07:50:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T07:50:11Z"},"LED":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"LED","price":3590,"transfers":0,"airline":"UT","flight_number":489,"departure_at":"2019-12-04T22:30:00Z","return_at":"2019-12-07T19:50:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T07:16:11Z"},"SIP":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"SIP","price":4881,"transfers":0,"airline":"N4","flight_number":133,"departure_at":"2019-12-07T12:35:00Z","return_at":"2019-12-11T08:55:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-26T15:41:27Z"},"TIV":{"origin":"MOW","destination":"TIV","price":6248,"transfers":0,"airline":"DP","flight_number":829,"departure_at":"2019-10-23T06:20:00Z","return_at":"2019-11-28T12:30:00Z","expires_at":"2019-07-28T03:08:27Z"}},"error":null,"currency":"RUB"}
```

Сейчас данные в виде обычных кубов (CSS). Мне необходимо преобразовать их в адаптивные блоки, в таком виде как у [сайт пример](https://avia.yandex.ru) с описанием. Что у меня не получается:

- 1) Не удается разбить данные АПИ, чтобы каждому блоку можно было
  присвоить свой класс.
- 2) Не удается соответственно присвоить внешний вид как у сайта
  примера Скрин ниже.

[image: Пример]

Спасибо.

Comment: Что за апи -  их много, какой язык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<?php
if(isset($products['data']) && is_array($products['data'])) {
  $contnum = 1;
foreach ($products['data'] as $key => $data) {
if (preg_match('/[A-Z]{3}/i', $key)) {
?>
<div class="<?='cont'.$contnum?>">

  <div class="content" style="width:100%!important;">
    <a rel="nofollow" alt="авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" title="Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?> туда обратно" href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=<?=$key?>&depart_date=<?=substr($data['departure_at'], 0, 10)?>&return_date=<?=substr($data['return_at'], 0, 10)?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">
      <div class="content-overlay"></div>
      <img alt="Дешевые авиабилеты Москва <?php echo $replace_value('destination',$key); ?>" class="content-image" src="/cities/world/<?= $key ?>-min.jpg"/>
      <h3 class="title"><?= $replace_value('destination',$key) ? $replace_value('destination', $key) : "<b>" .'Обновл.'. "</b>"; ?></h3><div class="content-details fadeIn-bottom">

        <p class="content-text" style="font-size: 20px;"><?= $data['price'] ?> руб.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
$contnum++;
}
}
}
?>
```